# How to display chinese character in 65001 in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am in win7 +python3.3.

```
import os
os.system("chcp  936")
fh=open("test.ch","w",encoding="utf-8")
fh.write("你")
fh.close()
os.system("chcp 65001")
fh=open("test.ch","r",encoding="utf-8").read()
print(fh)
Äã 
>>> print(fh.encode("utf-8"))
b'\xe4\xbd\xa0'
```

How can i display the chinese character  `你` in 65001?

Comment: NameError: name 'io' is not defined

Comment: >>> import sys  >>>import io
>>> sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding='utf-8')
>>> fh=open("test.ch","r",encoding="utf-8").read()
>>> print(fh)
浣?
>>> print(fh.encode("utf-8"))
b'\xe4\xbd\xa0'   problem remain.

Comment: problem solved.if you enter python by python(command line),the problem can't be solved.if you enter python by cmd ,and input `python`,no problem happen.

Answer (score 0):

If your terminal is capable of displaying the character directly (which it may not be due to font issues) then it should Just Work(tm).

```
>>> hex(65001)
>>> u"\ufde9"
'\ufde9'
>>> print(u"\ufde9")
﷩
```

To avoid the use of literals, note that in Python 3, at least, the `chr()` function will take a code point and return the associated Unicode character. So this works too, avoiding the need to do hex conversions.

```
>>> print(chr(65001))
﷩
```